# Method of Undetermined Coefficients - Efficient Way of Finding Constants

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y'' - 4y = (x^2 - 3)\sin(2x)$$

I have to solve the following differential equation. I have gotten everything setup. I have two questions however.

1. Is the form of the particular solution:

$y_p = (Ax^2 +Bx +C)\sin(2x) + (Dx^2 +Ex +F)\cos(2x)$

or

$y_p = (Ax^2 +Bx +C)(D\sin(2x) + E\cos(2x))$

2. If so, how can I quickly find the constants without having to do the extremely long, tedious and error-prone process of finding $y_p'', y_p'$ and plugging them in the differential equation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first form, and usually, there is no shortcut. Find a systematic and clear way to write down the derivatives without missing a term.

In this case, you can use that $\cos(2x)=Re(e^{i2x})$ and thus you can compute the particular solution for $(x^2-3)e^{i2x}$  and take the real part of it for the particular solution of the original problem. This is not really shorter since now the coefficients are complex numbers. However, the derivative formulas might be shorter, in addition to only having 3 named coefficients (with 6 real components).

---

\begin{align}
y_p'(x)&=(2Ax+B)·\sin(2x) + (Ax^2+Bx+C)·2\cos(2x)\\
    &\quad+(2Dx+E)·\cos(2x)-(Dx^2+Ex+F)·2\sin(x)\\ \\
&=(-2Dx^2+(2A-2E)x+(B-2F))\sin(2x)\\
    &\quad+(2Ax^2+(2B+2D)x+(2C+E))\cos(2x)
\end{align}
Yes, that looks like a lot of places to miss a factor of 2 or a sign.

Comment: I've tried it 3 times now and messed up with factoring and expanding haha. But thanks for answering. I'll try slowing down. My only concern is that I will fail to find them in an exam.

Comment: Break it down into small blocks. Compute $L(C\sin(2x)+F\cos(2x))$, $L(Bx\sin(2x)+Ex\cos(2x))$ etc. separately and add them together to the final formula. Or break them down even more.

Answer (score 2):

1. $y_p=\left(Ax^2+Bx+C\right)\sin{2x}+\left(Dx^2+Ex+F\right)\cos{2x}$, since it is the most general expression possible;
2. Unfortunately, you won't be able to avoid this tedious process. On the bright side, you'll have a lot of expressions equated to $0$.

Using the method of variation of parameters might be more effective.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'll try the wronskian method, although I usually leave that for forms not solvable by UC.